# How would I algebraically confirm shifting of parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was recently stumbled across this question on my workbook and i was wondering how to solve it.

> Consider the two parabolas y = x$^2$-4+3 and y=x$^2$+4x+3
>
> How can the second parabola be obtained by shifting the first?

I already know it is by shifting left by 4 units but how how can i show this algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f(x)$, the shift of $f$ by $a$ units is $f(x-a)$.  So take $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$.  Now compute $f(x+4)=(x+4)^2-4(x+4)+3=x^2+8x+16-4x-16+3=x^2+4x+3$.

To get a good picture of what's happening, you can also try *completing the square*.
One is $y=(x+2)^2-1$.  The other is $y=(x-2)^2-1$.  That means the first is a parabola opening upwards with vertex $(-2,-1)$; the second with vertex $(2,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
y&=x_{1}^{2}-4x_{1}+3\\
y&=x_{2}^{2}+4x_{2}+3\\
\\
0&=x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}^{2}-4x_{1}-4x_{2}\\
0&=(x_{1}+x_{2})(x_{1}-x_{2}-4)
\end{aligned}
$$

either $x_{1}=-x_{2}$ (parabolla reflected against $y$ axis or $x_{1}-x_{2}=4$ (parabolla translated by $4\hat{i}$)